# Load remote script files in background.js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, amazon-kinesis

This is my extension code

manifest.json

```
"background": {
  "page": "background.html"
},
```

background.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this approch is if the network is not connected at the start of chrome, the aws sdk file wont load, leading to failure of events associated with aws till the next chrome restart (extension restart).

I do not want to use unsafe-eval as it is not secure.

Is there a way to check for internet connectivity and reload this js file in background.js

I could alternatively download this script file and store it locally, but this would be my last solution.

Comment: Storing a file locally is usually the most straightforward solution, since it avoids several problems (network connectivity being one of them).  I'm not familiar with the script you're trying to load, but I'm having trouble thinking of situations where a background page needs a library.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Teepeemm The library is required for AWS Kinesis.which I am using to record user actions and browsing activities.Keeping a local copy serves my purpose, but I am not sure when the copy would be outdated.

Comment: If your copy is outdated, would it still record user actions and browsing activities?  Or does it communicate with Amazon?  I don't know that a background script would have access to user actions and browsing activities; you may want a content script instead.